# xamarin carousel page throws System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException on last page swipe only on Android

Tags: android, xamarin, carousel

Xamarin forms carousel page works of UWP but when running on Android the carousel page errors out on the last page when swiped. Instead of stopping an error occurs:

System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Specified argument was out of the range of valid values. Parameter name: index

Any help would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok managed to find the solution. One must set the ItemSource of the carousel view on the UI thread. I was setting it on a response from a WCF call which was on a new thread. I used Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(() => method call to resolve the issue.